# SIGABRT ABORT in QuartzCore

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm seeing crashlogs being generated containing the following call stack

```
    Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x38a0a1f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x38a74797 pthread_kill + 58
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x389bafdd abort + 76
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x38a32d67 free + 382
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3844e3ad object_dispose + 20
5  UIKit                          0x305511ef -[UIViewAnimationState dealloc] + 174
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0x38456b6b objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 174
7  CoreFoundation                 0x2dc2d93d CFRelease + 556
8  QuartzCore                     0x30195635 CA::release_objects(X::List<void const*>*) + 16
9  QuartzCore                     0x3019aad7 -[CAAnimation dealloc] + 54
10 libobjc.A.dylib                0x38456b6b objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 174
11 CoreFoundation                 0x2dc2d93d CFRelease + 556
12 QuartzCore                     0x3019d117 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 238
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x3892f81f _dispatch_client_callout + 22
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x3893649f _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 278
15 CoreFoundation                 0x2dcc78f1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
16 CoreFoundation                 0x2dcc61c5 __CFRunLoopRun + 1300
17 CoreFoundation                 0x2dc30f0f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
18 CoreFoundation                 0x2dc30cf3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
19 GraphicsServices               0x32b52663 GSEventRunModal + 138
20 UIKit                          0x3057c16d UIApplicationMain + 1136
21 Domino M                       0x000c125f main (main.m:14)
```

Other threads only show the AFNetworking library doing something.
How can I find and fix issues like this (the ones that don't seem to have anything to do with self written code)?

Comment: Add exception breakpoint, this could help you to solve the issue.

Comment: The exception breakpoint is enabled, but it does not break on any of my devices. Crashlytics says crashed thread but not fatal exception on this one. I assume this is somehting the user doesn't see this crash and therefore xcode doesn't break on it